Release Bundle v2 promotion in Artifactory
I've implemented Bundle Releases v2. I've added the required environments (DEV/QA/STAGING/PROD).
The bundle should be named and version when created, now as I'm gradually promoting my bundle to prod it remains with the same name and version for the bundle.
So if I have an internal version called qa-XXX and later on I want to promote it to a bundle version 1.0.0-rc1 there's no way to rename (or at least that's what I see in the API documentation).
I was expecting a feature that will allow me to rename the bundle version (not the bundle name) when promoting because qa-12345 may become 1.0.0 at some point according to the phase.
Do you have any idea how should I approach this issue?
Thanks.

As of now, Release-Bundle-v2 does not support modifying an existing Release Bundle after creation. Once a Release Bundle is created with a specific name and version, it becomes immutable and signed for security reasons.
Workaround
A practical workaround is to create a Release Bundle of another Release Bundle. Essentially, you can reference an existing Release Bundle within a new one.
Here’s an example payload:
{
"release_bundle_name": "Commons-Bundle",
"release_bundle_version": "1.0.0",
"source_type": "release_bundles",
"source": {
    "release_bundles": [
        {
            "project_key": "default",
            "repository_key": "release-bundles-v2",
            "release_bundle_name": "Commons-Bundle",
            "release_bundle_version": "qa-12345"
        }
    ]
},
"skip_docker_manifest_resolution": false

}

This will cause duplication and lack of correlation between the bundles and will also result in a very complicated way of managing the artifact location internally.
